# Karate - How to call multiple external features from a single main feature

Tags: testing, soap, cucumber, karate

```
Feature: Principal feature

Background:
    * url 'http://example.com'
   
    Scenario: Feature calling

       
    * def inputTable = call read('input_table.feature')  
    * call read('my_call.feature') inputTable.inputTestData
```

where the data table file is:

```
//input_table.feature
Feature:TABLE_TEST
Scenario:TABLE_TEST
    * table inputTestData
|inputName|outputName|
|requestA|responseA|
```

this throw me an error of:

```
ERROR com.intuit.karate - feature call failed: .../input_table.feature
arg: null
input_table.feature:3 - evaluation (js) failed: requestA, javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "requestA" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
stack trace: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
```

but instead if i call the my_call feature with the data table defined inside in the `Examples` field it works correctly.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a subtle difference between `Examples` and `table`. Maybe you meant to do this:

```
* table inputTestData
|inputName|outputName|
|'requestA'|'responseA'|
```

Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#table

Comment: I've already tried that but it throw an error as well: ERROR com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser - syntax error: extraneous input '\r\n\r\n ' expecting {EXAMPLES, STAR, GIVEN, WHEN, THEN, AND, BUT, TAGS}
line 55:1 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting TABLE_ROW
 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1]  ERROR com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser - syntax error: mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting TABLE_ROW
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1]  ERROR com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser - not a valid feature file: /my_call.feature - mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting TABLE_ROW

Comment: @ZhaledAsufian ok that does it for me. please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue